# Sorted Singly linked list to BST in place

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures

I have referred to many posts and answers but still not able to get a working code. Below is code for sorted linked list to BST in java. Included all helper functions for linked list.

Output which I is get is not expected i.e root : 4 , root.left is 2 and root.right is 4 again. I suppose output should be root : 4 , root.left is 2 and root.right is 6

```
class LNode {
    public int data;
    public LNode next;

    LNode(int newData) {
        this.data = newData;
    }
}

class Node {

    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Node prev;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    LNode first;
    LNode head;
    LNode newNode;

    public LinkedList() {
        first = null;
    }

    public void insertAtBeginning(int x) {
        newNode = new LNode(x);
        if (first != null) {
            newNode.next = first;
            first = newNode;
            head = first;
        } else {
            first = newNode;
            head = first;
        }
    }

    public void printList()

    {
        head = first;
        while (first != null) {
            System.out.print(first.data + " --> ");
            first = first.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
        first = head;

    }
}

public class LLtoBST {
    public static Node root;
    //public static LNode first;

    public static Node sortedListToBST(LNode first, int end) {

        return sortedListToBST(first, 0, end);
    }

    public static Node sortedListToBST(LNode first, int start, int end) {

        if (start > end)
            return null;
        if (first != null) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

            Node lnode = sortedListToBST(first, start, mid - 1);

            root = new Node(first.data);

            first = first.next;
            Node rnode = sortedListToBST(first, mid + 1, end);

            root.left = lnode;
            root.right = rnode;

        }
        return root;

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        int n = 0;
        list.insertAtBeginning(7);
        list.insertAtBeginning(6);
        list.insertAtBeginning(5);
        list.insertAtBeginning(4);
        list.insertAtBeginning(3);
        list.insertAtBeginning(2);
        list.insertAtBeginning(1);
        list.printList();

        first = list.head;

        while (first != null) {
            n++;
            first = first.next;
        }

        first = list.head;

        Node curr = sortedListToBST(first, n);
        System.out.println(curr.data);
        System.out.println(curr.left.data);
        System.out.println(curr.right.data);

    } 

}

Output :
1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> null
4
2
4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please make the below changes in the function **sortedListToBST(LNode first, int start, int end)**

Please note that the below code prints 2 as the left child of 4 and 6 as the right child of 4. Also, I have tested the code with 2 and 6 as roots. It prints 1 as the left child of 2 and 3 as the right child of 2. Also, 5 as the left child of 6 and 7 as the right child of 6.

Please also note that you need to change your test client so that it handles the use case when the left child and/or the right child are/is null. I hope the below code is helpful.

The below algorithm works on the principle of in-order traversal of tree.

1. Traverse the left subtree.
2. Visit the root.
3. Traverse the right subtree.

   ```
   public static Node sortedListToBST(LNode first, int start, int end) {

   if (start > end)
       return null;

   int mid = (start + end) / 2;
   Node leftNode = sortedListToBST(first, start, mid - 1);
   Node root = new Node(first.data);
   root.left = leftNode;
   if (first.next != null) {
       first.data = first.next.data;
       first.next = first.next.next;
   }

   root.right = sortedListToBST(first, mid + 1, end);
   return root;

   }
   ```

Comment: Great!! The solution works...Can you explain the logic behind this                                                        if (first.next != null) {
    first.data = first.next.data;
    first.next = first.next.next;
}                                                                                                        Wondering why this does not work                                                              if (first.next != null) {
    first= first.next;
}

Comment: Any insights on the question posted recently?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify that a **balanced** BST is required. If you are happy with unbalanced BST, the following works:

```
 public static Node sortedListToUnbalancedBST(LNode lNode) {
     if (lNode.next != null) {
         Node node = new Node(lNode.data);
         node.right = sortedListToUnbalancedBST(lNode.next);
         return node;
     } else {
        return null;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys the question is convert bst to sorted singly linked list in java

```
class SortedLL {
    LinkedListNode<Integer> head;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> tail;
}

public class Solution {

    public static SortedLL sortedLL(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {

        if (root == null) {
            SortedLL output = new SortedLL();
            output.head = null;
            output.tail = null;
            return output;
        }

        SortedLL l = sortedLL(root.left);
        SortedLL r = sortedLL(root.right);

        LinkedListNode<Integer> n = new LinkedListNode<Integer>(root.data);

        if (l.tail != null) {
            l.tail.next = n;
        }

        if (r.head != null) {
            n.next = r.head;
        }

        SortedLL b = new SortedLL();

        if (l.head != null) {
            b.head = l.head;
        } else {
            b.head = n;
        }

        if (r.tail != null) {
            b.tail = r.tail;
        } else {
            b.tail = n;
        }

        return b;
    }

    public static LinkedListNode<Integer> BSTToSortedLL(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {
        return sortedLL(root).head;
    }
}
```